# select first element css base on class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
.class + p:first-child{

}
```

the above code not working, unless it's element instead of class, like p:first-child.

```
<div class="wrap">
<h3></h3>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

how do I select first `p` base on the class wrap? I do not want to apply class name on `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `:first-child` here, because in this case `first-child` of `class:wrap` is `<h3>` .In your desired case try this

```
.wrap > p:nth-of-type(1) {
    color:red

}
```

Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9H7Dp/2/)